# Number of "Votes cast" for the week is bigger than the number for the month

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, voting

The two stats: "1 vote last month" and "2 votes last week" are mutually exclusive.

Observed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762224/mr-polywhirl?tab=topactivity) on Feb 1st and 2nd:

[image: "votes cast" on Stackoverflow profile]

Answer (score 7):

The *month* here is calendar month, so: the dates 1st February-current.

The *week* here is Sunday-to-Sunday, so: the dates 29th January-current.

Presumably they voted at some point during the 29th-31st January.

They are not contradictory - just a little unusual looking at the start of the month.

Comment: Thanks for demystifying this Marc. If the month meant by "last month" is this month, the text should be changed to say "this". "last" means previous in this context. Same thing goes for the week.

Comment: @Web_Designer if the code said "last month", I would agree with you; however, it says "in the last month", which commonly (and confusingly) is used to mean the same as "this month"; similar to the top answer here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131162/in-the-last-month-vs-last-month - although we're treating the cutoffs differently

Comment: You're right "last month" and "in the last month" are different. But, as pointed out by that English SE answer, "in the last month" means "in the last 30 days". So there is a problem with using "in the last month" to mean "this month".

Comment: Is this really [tag:status-bydesign] then?